# Count common columns values between data frames (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple tables as below.
There are 10 df tables with rows ranging from 1000-25,000 rows.
These df tables are produced after clustering them. Thus, the difference in number of rows.

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5], 'segments' : ["a,b,c", "c,a", "d,a,b", "e,g", "a,e,d"]})
  ref = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,4], 'segments' : ["a,b,c", "e,g"]})
```

> ```
>      | id | segments |
> +----+----+----------+
> | 0  | 1  | a,b,c    |
> | 1  | 2  | c,a      | 
> | 2  | 3  | d,a,b    | 
> | 3  | 4  | e,g      | 
> | 4  | 5  | a,e,d    | 
> +----+----+----------+  ....total 1500-25,000 rows (10 df tables)
>
>
>      | id | segments |
> +----+----+----------+
> | 0  | 1  | a,b,c    |
> | 1  | 4  | e,g      | 
> +----+----+----------+.....total 1216 rows
> ```

My aim is to determine if the ref ID exists in each df table. 
If yes, I need to check each rows of each df table and count how many segments are the same. 
My final output will be as followed.

> ```
>      | id | segments |ref_1  | ref_2
> +----+----+----------+-------+-----+
> | 0  | 1  | a,b,c    | 3     |  0  |
> | 1  | 2  | c,a      | 2     |  0  |
> | 2  | 3  | d,a,b    | 2     |  0  |
> | 3  | 4  | e,g      | 0     |  2  |
> | 4  | 5  | a,e,d    | 1     |  1  |
> +----+----+----------+-------+-----+
> ```

So far, I've determined how to check if the ref ID is present

```
# get the ref id present in df
for index, row in enumerate(df.id):
    for index2, row2 in enumerate(ref.id):
        if row == row2:
            print("ref id present")
            print(row,index)
        else:
            "no ref id"
```

I have tried to use the intersection function. But I got output 0.

```
len(set(df['segments']).intersection(set(ref['segments'])))
```

I did my research but most of the solution involves single column values where it is solved using merge.  However, mine has multiple values in 1 column. 
 
I'm stuck for 2 days on how to check and count the common values and to put it all in a loop to perform on 10 df tables.

Comment: This should work df = df[df['segments'].isin(ref['segments'])].groupby('segments', as_index=False)['segments'].agg(['count'])

Comment: I need to find the number of common values. Meaning df = [a,c] and ref id1 =[a,g,e] then the output value should be 1 (common value is a). Your solution takes [a,g,e] vs [a,c]. Since they're not exactly same, output is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need create sets with `split` and then compare by `set.intersection`:

```
segments = [set(x.split(',')) for x in df['segments']]
ref = [set(x.split(',')) for x in ref['segments']]

for i, x in enumerate(ref, 1):
    df['ref_{}'.format(i)] = [len(y.intersection(x)) for y in segments]
print (df)
   id segments  ref_1  ref_2
0   1    a,b,c      3      0
1   2      c,a      2      0
2   3    d,a,b      2      0
3   4      e,g      0      2
4   5    a,e,d      1      1
```

Another solution (O(n)) if performance is important:

```
for i, x in enumerate(ref, 1):
    df['ref_{}'.format(i)] = [len([val for val in x if val in y]) for y in segments]
```

Comment: Ah, so split the segments by its comma, change it to set and then find intersection. This works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user123 - Yes, fun is the hardest for me was understand output ;) You are welcome!